# Do I need `browserslist` and `caniuse-lite` packages in my Angular 16 app

Tags: angular, browserslist

I'm cleaning up some dependencies of my Angular project.

I noticed that we have have an old `.browserslistrc` file, and `package.json` contains both `browserslist` and `caniuse-lite` packages. Is this something I need to have as dependencies, does Angular handle that by default already?

Reading the following https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility it says we have the option to override the internal configuration.

So if I just delete those packages, will Angular still handle everything properly, using it's default supported browsers?